# Compute possible combinations of an equation

Tags: python

I've got a template of equations `template = (a op b) op c` where the available operations `op` are the following: `op = ['+', '-', '/', '*']`.

What I want to do is to compute all the possible combinations of this equation using the operations `op` and the parameters `a`, `b` and `c`.

e.g.

```
(a + b) + c
(a - b) - c
(a * b) * c
(a / b) / c
(a + c) + b
(a - c) + b
(b * a) - c
...
...
...
```

I had a look at `itertools.combinations` however I am not quite sure if (or how) I can use this function in this particular context.

Comment: put your code,  what you have tried yet. That will clear more

Comment: Build all the possibilities by using string concatenation, then parse one by one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: You want the *cartesian product* of your operators, not the combinations. `itertools.product(op, repeat=2)` generates those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
import itertools

symbol = ['a', 'b', 'c']
op = ['+', '-', '/', '*']

for symbols in itertools.permutations(symbol):
    for ops in itertools.product(op, repeat=2):
        print "(%s %s %s) %s %s" % (
            symbols[0], ops[0], symbols[1], ops[1], symbols[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need three things here:

- The permutations of your three variable: (a,b,c), (a,c,b), (b,c,a), etc.
- The cartesian product of your operation set with itself: (*, -), (-, +), (+, -), (+, +), etc.
- The cartesian product between the variables permutations and the previous product.

So, using the glorious `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it

vars = 'abc'
ops = '+-/*'

vars_permutations = it.permutations(vars)
op_permutations = it.product(ops, repeat=2)

for var, op in it.product(vars_permutations, op_permutations):
    print('({} {} {}) {} {}'.format(var[0], op[0], var[1], op[1], var[2]))
```